# SQL Junção JOIN

Tags: sql

Eu preciso elaborar uma consulta que traga a matrícula do funcionário, nome do funcionário e o nome da cidade do funcionário usando `JOIN`. Mas como não tenho experiência ainda com essa função, estou empacado!! Para isso eu tenho a tabela `funcionario` e a tabela `cidade`. Até agora eu tenho isso:

```
select * from funcionario, cidade

select funcionario.matfunc, funcionario.nome, cidade.nome
from funcionario, cidade
where funcionario.nome = cidade.nome
```

Agora em diante estou travado pois não peguei o lance do `JOIN`.

Comment: Há bastante conteúdo sobre joins aqui no forum. Segue um tópico que explica muito bem o assunto. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join Depois de ler tente refazer suas consultas e poste as eventuais dúvidas. Boa sorte!

Comment: Quais são os campos das tabelas, qual campo armazena o código da cidade na tabela `funcionario`?

Comment: Funcionario
matfunc        nome          cpf         dtnasc        CODCID          codchef


Cidade
CODCID           nome          cep         uf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estava quase lá, a comparação tem que ser `codcid` da tabela `funcionario` com `codcid` da tabela `cidade`.

```
select funcionario.matfunc, funcionario.nome, cidade.nome
from funcionario, cidade
where funcionario.codcid = cidade.codcid
```

Isso acima já é um `JOIN`, mas você pode deixa-lo mais explícito e de mais fácil compreensão da seguinte forma:

```
select funcionario.matfunc, funcionario.nome, cidade.nome
from funcionario
JOIN cidade ON funcionario.codcid = cidade.codcid
```

[Nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) pergunta tem bastante coisa interessante sobre todos os tipos de `JOIN`.

Comment: Bah..eu não achei que a comparação deveria ser o CODCID. Imaginei que isso me traria apenas o código e não o nome da cidade.

Comment: Pois é, a comparação é uma coisa e os campos que serão retornados é outra. Se a resposta resolveu o problema, marque-a como a solução!

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, poste como está a estrutura das duas tabelas. e quais os campos deseja mostrar.

a estrutura do inner join seria algo assim:

```
select * from funcionarios left outer join cidades on funcionarios.cid_cli = cidades.cod_cidade
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Mas agora consegui pegar esse lance do JOIN. Abraços!!